# How to return DataSet with WebService between webform and windows phone

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to ASP.net. I am trying to retrieve some database data from the server side. I created a web service and added a service reference to my mobile phone app (consumer). Everything works well when it is only returning a single data (such as `int` or `string`).

Working code as below:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ServiceRef.MyServiceClient sevRef = new ServiceRef.MyServiceClient();
        sevRef.retrieveValCompleted += svc_retrieveValCompleted;
        sevRef.retrieveValAsync("05");  //method retrieveVal("") return string 
        //How to handle a method which returns DataSet?
    }

    private void svc_retrieveValCompleted(object sender, retrieveValCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            textBlock.Text = e.Error.ToString();
        else
            textBlock.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Now my question is**: I wanted to retrieve the entire table from the database and store it in a DataSet. How do we do that? I am asking this because unlike web service from webform to webform where it can return datatype of DataSet.
In mobile app, I can only find `methodCompleted` and `methodAsync()`. There is no method returning `DataSet` even after I added a new method returning `DataSet` at the server side (and updated it at the consumer side).

*P.S: Please cut my some slack if I used the wrong terminology for ASP.NET. I am trying my best to use the correct terms and make my question clear.*

Answer (score 0):

You can decide to use Json to serialize and deserialize data. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json.